# How to merge intersections in a text?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to convert this word into a solid object for 3d printing. But I'm having trouble to merge this intersections. How can I convert this kind of word into a solid object with no intersections?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Delete the intersections then bridge the required verts each other by selecting them and hit F.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the characters of the word are single object, because you want them one object ... so they aren't one object...

Select F and assign a boolean modifier.
For the "object" (see the modifiers panel) assign the "l".
Set mode to "union".
Apply the modifier.
That will give you one object consisting of "Fl" and the "l", which had
not modifier assigned to it...delete the "l".
Now do the same with the "Fl"-object (assign modifier to it) and the "o",
apply, remove the "o". Now "Flo" and the "w" and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! :)